# Generic asp.net table not Displayed

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have the following code to create a string that contains a aspTable.

```
private void createTabel()
{
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

    html.Append("<asp:Table runat='server'>");

    //Header Row erstellen.
    html.Append("<asp:TableHeaderRow>");
    foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        html.Append("<asp:TableHeaderCell>");
        html.Append(column.ColumnName);
        html.Append("</asp:TableHeaderCell>");
    }
    html.Append("</asp:TableHeaderRow>");

    //Erstellen der Rows.
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        html.Append("<asp:TableRow>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<asp:TableCell>");
            html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
            html.Append("</asp:TableCell>");
        }
        html.Append("</asp:TableRow>");
    }


    html.Append("</asp:Table>");


    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });


}
```

This code works fine and it creates a string that should display a asp.net Table.

If I manual paste it in a HTML doc everything is displayed well. But if I replace my `PlaceHolder` it displays only a large `string` with the content of the rows.

I hope you guy can give me a hint to fix my Problem.

Comment: `asp:Table` is server control which gets rendered into `<table>`. If you want to add html to `PlaceHolder`, use `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` tags

Comment: so it's not possible to add a asp:table through that way

Comment: nope. use kzee's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
private void createTabel()
    {
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

        html.Append("<table>");

        //Header Row erstellen.
        html.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append(column.ColumnName);
            html.Append("</th>");
        }
        html.Append("</tr>");

        //Erstellen der Rows.
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</td>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");
        }

        html.Append("</table>");

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
    }
```

Alternatively, you may just use GridView and bind dataTable to GridView as DataSource.